# \cite{} via apacite package not working

Tags: bibtex, citing, apacite

I'm writing my first LaTeX document using Texmaker (v5.0.2) and Windows 10.

When trying to use the apacite package and bibtex to do my citations/references I get a wired output. For citations outside of figure captions, it outputs "(?, ?, p. x-y)" where "x-y" are the page numbers. For citations within figure captions I get a compile error, where the log states: -

"! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.

You meant to type ## instead of #, right? Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##."

I find this error to be particularly weird since my source code does not contain any hashtags anywhere.

Additionally, my bibliography does not appear, despite having

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{citations.bib}
```

in my source code.

Here's my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin = 2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{apacite}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
```

Here's my bib file:

```
@book{HistOfMaths,
    author = {Boyer, Carl B. and Merzbch, Uta C.},
    year = {1991},
    title = {A history of mathematics},
    edition = {2nd},
    city = {New York},
    publisher = {Wiley} }

@online{DrawGraph,
    author = {Kummer, J.},
    year = {n.d.},
    title = {Draw Function Graph},
    url = {https://rechneronline.de/function-graphs/},
    lastchecked = {2018-01-05} }

@misc{PaintThreeD,
    title = {Paint 3d (Version 5.1806.20057.0) [Computer software]},
    year = {2017},
    address = {Redmond, Washington},
    publisher = {Author},
    url = {https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/paint-3d/9nblggh5fv99} }

@book{Elements,
    author = {Euclid,},
    translator = {Heath, T. L.},
    editor = {Densmore, D.},
    originalyear = {2002},
    year = {2017},
    title = {Euclid's Elements},
    address = {Santa Fe, New Mexico},
    publisher = {Green Lion Press} }

@book{Cantor,
    author = {Cantor, Georg},
    translator = {Jourdain, Philip E. B.},
    originalyear = {1915},
    year = {2009},
    title = {Contributions to the Founding of the Theory of Transfinite Numbers},
    address = {London},
    publisher = {BiblioLife} }
```

Here's an example of one of my citations outside a figure caption:

```
The fraktur, lowercase $\mathfrak{c}$ referring to the continuum \cite[p.~95]{Cantor}.
```

Lastly, here's an example of my of my citations within a figure caption (yes, yes, I know I should be using vector graphics, not bitmap):

```
\begin{figure}[t] \label{fig1}
\begin{center}
\fbox{ \includegraphics{Figures/Figure-1} }
\end{center}
\caption{bla bla bla. Created using \cite{DrawGraph} \cite{PaintThreeD}.}
\end{figure}
```

One last thing, for some reason when I try to use the `\citep{}` function it outputs an error stating that `\citep{}` is an undefined function, **despite** the function appearing in the drop-down menu as I type it. This is not essential for my document, but a fix would be appreciated.

Regards,

A LaTeX novice who's about to pluck his eye's out so he doesn't have to look at this crap anymore

Comment: Tackle one problem at the time. Remove cites from caption for now. Press F6 in your keyboard, then press F11, then F6 two times more.

Comment: Have you thought about reading introductory material first? You are using a template you found somewhere or someone gave you, you are confusing several ways of bibliography and citation creation.

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports and https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Citations_and_Bibliographies for a thesis I would recommend biblatex with biber.

Comment: @Johannes_B I'll take a look at the documentation. Thanks Johannes